# Clean a dataset, set rows to NA based on different columns and different values

Tags: r, dataframe, na

My dataset looks like this:

I would like to clean it so that all rows are NA when "QR" shows C:

```
    SO4     PO4 LabConductivity  LabPH Notes   QR
1 0.131 0.00100            3.98   5.25   dmz    B
2 0.109 0.00126            3.54   5.27    mz    B
3 0.219 -0.5656            6.28   5.23  <NA>    A
4 0.219 -0.5656            6.28  -5.66  <NA>    C
5 0.219 -0.5656            6.28   5.23  <NA>    C
```

So I can do that doing this:

```
mydata[mydata$QR=="C",] <- NA
```

However, I would like to keep doing that for other variables, e.g. set entire row to NA when LabPH is >6 OR <0.

If I do the same thing again I get the following warning:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, mydata$LabPH > 5 | mydata$LabPH < 0,  : missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
```

Is there another way of doing this? IS there an ignoreNAfunction for that case?
Or is there an entirely better way of doing this?

Thanks  so much in advance
cheers
Sandra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.frame` cannot subset if you have `NA` at the column you use to do the logical test. For example, you can see the rows with `LabPH = NA` are not subsetted.

```
> mydata[mydata$LabPH > 5.25,]
   SO4     PO4 LabConductivity LabPH Notes   QR
   2    0.109 0.00126            3.54  5.27    mz    B
   NA      NA      NA              NA    NA  <NA> <NA>
   NA.1    NA      NA              NA    NA  <NA> <NA>
```

`which` works because it excludes those rows with `LabPH = NA`, another way to do this is to use `!is.na()` to exclude the `NA`

```
> new <- mydata[!is.na(mydata$LabPH)&mydata$LabPH > 5.25,]
> new
    SO4     PO4 LabConductivity LabPH Notes QR
2 0.109 0.00126            3.54  5.27    mz  B
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a `which` to your logical test.

For example,

`mydata[which(mydata$LabPh > 5.25),] <- NA`

Comment: That works...but why? Is it because it only looks at the cases where the condition is true and hence ignores the NAs that might be present in the column that I am using for indexing?

Answer (score 0):

Is it not replacing the entire row with `NA` is as good as excluding the data? If so, considering your condisions `(QR = "C" and LabPH = between 0 to 6)`, here is a way to do that...

```
# Please note I added a random 6th row with LabPH = 7.0. 

SO4 = c(0.131,0.109,0.219,0.219,0.219,0.21)
PO4 = c(0.00100,0.00126,-0.5656,-0.5656,-0.5656,-0.532)
LabConductivity = c(3.98, 3.54, 6.28, 6.28, 6.28,6.25)
LabPH = c(5.25,5.27,5.23,-5.66,5.23,7.0)
Notes = c("dmz","mz","<NA>","<NA>","<NA>","mz")
QR = c("B","B","A","C","C","B")

# create a data frame
df = data.frame(SO4,PO4,LabConductivity,LabPH,Notes,QR)
df

    SO4      PO4 LabConductivity LabPH Notes QR
1 0.131  0.00100            3.98  5.25   dmz  B
2 0.109  0.00126            3.54  5.27    mz  B
3 0.219 -0.56560            6.28  5.23  <NA>  A
4 0.219 -0.56560            6.28 -5.66  <NA>  C
5 0.219 -0.56560            6.28  5.23  <NA>  C
6 0.210 -0.53200            6.25  7.00    mz  B
```

# Subset based on your condition

```
df[which((df$LabPH > 0 & df$LabPH < 6) & df$QR != "C"),]
# output
   SO4     PO4    LabConductivity LabPH Notes QR
1 0.131  0.00100            3.98  5.25   dmz  B
2 0.109  0.00126            3.54  5.27    mz  B
3 0.219 -0.56560            6.28  5.23  <NA>  A
```